# How to fit a huge table on latex?

Tags: tables

I'm starting with latex and I'm trying to display a huge table for a document, I have read some answers where the table was too long or too wide so specific answers were made for those. Still, my table is huge in both dimensions so I don't know how to approach this.

I'm thinking maybe the best way would be to display it in 4 pages (1st and 3rd pages being the top and bottom of the left side of the table, and 2nd and 4th pages being the top and bottom of the right side of the table, still, I don't know how to code this or if it would be enough.

I'm using letter size paper, and my table is the next one:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Parámetro & Atributo de Calidad & Método de testeo & Nivel de análisis & Rango de Humira (EU) & Referencia \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Estructura primaria} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Secuencia de aminoácidos} & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & Cromatograma puede superponerse visualmente a Humira & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & LC/MS/MS (mapeos de péptidos ortogonales) & 3 & Secuencia de aminoácidos idéntica para ambas cadenas & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Puentes disulfuro & LC/MS (mapeo de péptidos en condiciones no reductoras) & 3 & Porcentaje relativo similar de enlaces
Disulfuro correctamente unidos & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Tioles libres & Ensayo de Ellman & 3 & Baja cantidad de tioles libres ($\leq$ 0.4 mol / mol) & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Enlaces tioéter & rCE-SDS & 3 & Baja cantidad de enlaces tioéter
Del pico de la cadena ligera-pesada & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Masa molecular} & UPLC-ESI-MS de proteína intacta (2H2L + 2G0F) / ESI-TOF-MS & 3 & 148.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & UPLC-ESI- MS - (R) de cadena pesada y cadena ligera & 3 & HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & UPLC-ESI-MS - (R / NR) de mAb desglicosilado (2H2L), LC, HC & 3 & 2H2L: 145.2 kDa. HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa,  & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & SE-HPLC / MALLS de monómero & 3 & 143.8-154.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Punto Isoeléctrico & cIEF & 3 & 8.45-8.46 & Amgen \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Pureza} & \% Principal & SE-HPLC & 2 & 99.2-99.6\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Monómeros & SEC & 2 & 99.5-99.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Variantes de peso molecular alto} & SEC & 2 & 0.1-0.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & AUC & 2 & 0-2.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Dímeros & AUC & 3 & 0.5-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Fragmentos de mAb} & SEC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{nrCE-SDS} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{2} & LC: 0.1-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 5- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & HHL: 1.4-3.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & IgG intacta & nrCE-SDS & 2 & 95.6-97.9\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Glicosilación} & Ocupación del sitio Fc N-glicano & rCE-SDS & 3 & 97.7-98.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Identificación de glicanos & UPLC-ESI-MS/MS con procainamida & 3 & 14 glicanos detectados & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & N-glicano galactosilado & HILIC & 2 & 14.7-23.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & N-glicano no-fucosilado + alto en manosa & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 6.2-11.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & N-glicano no-fucosilado & HILIC & 2 & 0.5-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & N-glicano alto en manosa & HILIC & 2 & 3.9-6.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & N-glicano sialilado & HILIC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \%G0F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 65.8-71.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \%G1F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 12.8-16.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \%G2F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 0.9-1.5\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Glicación & Cromatografía de afinidad de boronato & 3 & 0.1-0.6\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Carga} & Variantes acídas & CEX & 2 & 8.2-12.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Variantes básicas & CEX & 2 & 20.6-31.5\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Pico principal} & CEX-UPLC & 2 & 17.5-30.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & icIEF & 2 & 18.5-30.1\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Variantes isoeléctricas} & cIEF & 3 & Patrón de carga similar y variantes de punto isoeléctrico & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & 2D-DIGE & 3 & Imagen similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
Hidrofobicidad & Hidrofobicidad & HIC & 3 & Perfil similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Modificaciones de aminoácidos /
Variantes de secuencia} & Oxidación de Met256 y Met34 & RP-HPLC-UV & 2 & 0.9-2.9\% & Sandoz, Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Deamidación en péptidos LH27 y LH30 & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.3-4.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Isomerización de Asp} & ISOQUANT & 3 & 0.8-2.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 0.5-2.8\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Extensión N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & Sin detección de escisión incompleta del péptido & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Piroglutamato N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.2-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Lisina C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 13.3-18.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Prolina amida C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & 0.1-1.4\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Estructura de orden superior} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Estructura secundaria} & CD  UV-lejano & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & FTIR & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Estructura terciaria} & CD UV-cercano & 3 & Estructura terciaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Cristalografía de rayos X & 3 & Estructura cristalina similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Intercambio H / D & 3 & Estructura 3D similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Coeficiente de extinción} & AAA / Pico Tag  & 3 & 1.47-1.49 & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} &  ACCQ Tag & 3 & 1.38 & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Temperatura de fusión & DSC & 3 & Tm1: 71.06, Tm2: 81.56 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Estructura 3D} & 1D 1H NMR & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & 2D 1H-1H NMR  & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Atributos relacionados
Con el medicamento} & Osmolalidad (mOsm/kg) & Osmómetro (depresión del punto de congelación de la solución) & 3 & 0.80-0.81 & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & pH & Potenciómetro & 3 & 5.2-5.3 & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Claridad & Inspección visual & 3 & Sin color a levemente amarilla & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Polisorbato 80 & Espectrofotometría de absorción infrarroja & 3 & 0.09\% & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Volumen extraíble & Peso & 2 & 771-831 $\upmu$L & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Contaminación por partículas} & Inspección visual & 3 & Libre de partículas extrañas & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & MFI & 3 & $\geq$ 10 $\upmu$m: 104-208, $\geq$ 25 $\upmu$m: 1-2 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & RMM & 3 & No flotantes> 0.3 $\upmu$m: 5000-9000, 
Flotantes> 0.5 $\upmu$m: 2000-4000  & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Concentración de ingrediente activo  & UVS (280 nm) & 2 &  44.9-52.4 mg/mL & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Actividad Biológica} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Unión a TNF} & Inhibición de la apoptosis celular inducida por sTNF-$\upalpha$ & 1 & 84-118\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión al TNF$\upalpha$ por SPR / por FRET & 1 & 80-120\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Estimulación de la apoptosis de células Jurkat inducida por mTNF-$\upalpha$ & 2 & 87-117\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Neutralización de TNF-$\upalpha$ (ensayo de gen reportero NF-k$\upbeta$) & 2 & 78-115\% & Sandoz, Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión mTNF por citometría de flujo & 2 & 80-113\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Inhibición de la expresión de la molécula de adhesión sVCAM-1 & 3 & 95-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a las citocinas: TGF-$\upbeta$1, IL-1$\upbeta$, IFN-$\upgamma$, 
APRIL, IL-6, IL- 8, IL-10, TNF-beta, sCD40L, BAFF y RANKL & 3 & No se presenta & Sandoz, Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Inducción de células reguladoras
(señalización inversa)} & Ensayo MLR: incorporación de EdU por citometría de flujo & 3 & 0-70\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Expresión de macrófagos reguladores (CD206) por citometría de flujo & 3 & 69-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{ADCC} & Ensayo de ADCC de células NK & 2 & 54-182\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & MLR & 3 & Inhibe la proliferación de células T
De una manera proporcional a la dosis & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa V158 por SPR & 2 & 69-115\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa F158 por SPR & 2 & 79-99\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{CDC} & Ensayo CDC & 2 & 65-119\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a C1q por ELISA & 2 & 70-111\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Ensayos SPR adicionales de unión
Al receptor Fc$\upgamma$} & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RI M 10-9 & 3 & 20.3-24.5 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIa $\upmu$M & 3 & 2.27-2.34 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIb/c $\upmu$M & 3 & 9.48-10.0 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIb & 3 & 9.67-11.8 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Vida media & Unión al receptor de FcRn por SPR & 2 & 67-150\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Degradación } & 50 °C (2 semanas) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 40 °C (3 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 25 °C (6 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Exposición lumínica & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Deamidación forzada & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Oxidación forzada & Endopeptidasa de lisilo limitada & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Impurezas relacionadas al proceso} & Proteina A & ELISA & 3 & < 1 ng/mg & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{Proteinas celulares} & HCP ELISA & 3 & 129-168 ppm & Amgen \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{} & 2D DIGE & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & DNA residual & qPCR & 3 & < 1pg/mg & Amgen \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Inmunogenicidad} & Ensayo ADA & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Ensayo Nab & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Estudios Preclínicos} & Estudio toxicológico/toxicocinético & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Estudio farmacocinético comparativo & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & Estudio farmacológico & Monos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Sandoz \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Resumen de pruebas de presentadas por Amgen, Samsung, Sandoz y Pfizer para sustentar la demostración de biocomparabilidad de sus productos contra Humira (Amgen, 2016; Pfizer, 2019; Samsung, 2018; Sandoz, 2018), primera columna: Parámetro, segunda columna: atributo de calidad a medir, tercera columna, método utilizado para la medición, cuarta columna: nivel de análisis: nivel 1: Análisis de equivalencia estadística $\pm$ 1.5$\upsigma$ (Amgen, 2016), nivel 2: respeta el rango de calidad establecido para Humira $\pm$ 3$\upsigma$  (Sandoz, 2018) nivel 3: Visualmente similar a Humira (comparación de resultados lado a lado), quinta columna: datos pertenecientes a Humira, quinta columna: referencia. }
\label{}
\end{table}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete, self contained document, which we can test as it is. Where is defined `\upmu` ?

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and missing definitions. How to make a table fit into your page depends on the page, margin and font size, so please also add these setting as well.

Comment: AFAICT, *none* of the plentiful `\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{}` and `\multicolumn{ 1}{c|}{}` directives do anything useful. Moreover, the `\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{...}` wrappers don't do anything useful either. Why are they there?

Answer (score 2):

Here are three different version using `xltabular`. The first version makes your table fit onto portrait pages, the second one onto landscape pages. The third one contains quite a lot of redesign, less lines and a removed first column to save some space.

Probably one of the following examples can serve as a point to start from.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|c|L|c|}
\caption{Resumen de pruebas de presentadas por Amgen, Samsung, Sandoz y Pfizer para sustentar la demostración de biocomparabilidad de sus productos contra Humira (Amgen, 2016; Pfizer, 2019; Samsung, 2018; Sandoz, 2018), primera columna: Parámetro, segunda columna: atributo de calidad a medir, tercera columna, método utilizado para la medición, cuarta columna: nivel de análisis: nivel 1: Análisis de equivalencia estadística $\pm$ 1.5$\upsigma$ (Amgen, 2016), nivel 2: respeta el rango de calidad establecido para Humira $\pm$ 3$\upsigma$  (Sandoz, 2018) nivel 3: Visualmente similar a Humira (comparación de resultados lado a lado), quinta columna: datos pertenecientes a Humira, quinta columna: referencia. }
\label{}\\
\hline
\thead{Parámetro} 
  & \thead{Atributo de\\ Calidad} 
    & \thead{Método de\\ testeo} 
      & \thead{Nivel de\\ análisis} 
        & \thead{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)} 
          & \thead{Referencia} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \thetable:{} -- continued from previous page}\\
\hline
\thead{Parámetro} 
  & \thead{Atributo de\\ Calidad} 
    & \thead{Método de\\ testeo} 
      & \thead{Nivel de\\ análisis} 
        & \thead{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)} 
          & \thead{Referencia} \\ \hline
\endhead
Estructura primaria & Secuencia de aminoácidos & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & Cromatograma puede superponerse visualmente a Humira & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
 &  & LC/MS/MS (mapeos de péptidos ortogonales) & 3 & Secuencia de aminoácidos idéntica para ambas cadenas & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Puentes disulfuro & LC/MS (mapeo de péptidos en condiciones no reductoras) & 3 & Porcentaje relativo similar de enlaces
Disulfuro correctamente unidos & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Tioles libres & Ensayo de Ellman & 3 & Baja cantidad de tioles libres ($\leq$ 0.4 mol / mol) & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Enlaces tioéter & rCE-SDS & 3 & Baja cantidad de enlaces tioéter
Del pico de la cadena ligera-pesada & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Masa molecular & UPLC-ESI-MS de proteína intacta (2H2L + 2G0F) / ESI-TOF-MS & 3 & 148.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
 &  & UPLC-ESI- MS - (R) de cadena pesada y cadena ligera & 3 & HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
 &  & UPLC-ESI-MS - (R / NR) de mAb desglicosilado (2H2L), LC, HC & 3 & 2H2L: 145.2 kDa. HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa,  & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & SE-HPLC / MALLS de monómero & 3 & 143.8-154.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Punto Isoeléctrico & cIEF & 3 & 8.45-8.46 & Amgen \\ \hline
Pureza & \% Principal & SE-HPLC & 2 & 99.2-99.6\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Monómeros & SEC & 2 & 99.5-99.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Variantes de peso molecular alto & SEC & 2 & 0.1-0.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & AUC & 2 & 0-2.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Dímeros & AUC & 3 & 0.5-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Fragmentos de mAb & SEC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & nrCE-SDS & 2 & LC: 0.1-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 5- 6}
  &   &   &   & HHL: 1.4-3.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & IgG intacta & nrCE-SDS & 2 & 95.6-97.9\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Glicosilación & Ocupación del sitio Fc N-glicano & rCE-SDS & 3 & 97.7-98.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Identificación de glicanos & UPLC-ESI-MS/MS con procainamida & 3 & 14 glicanos detectados & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano galactosilado & HILIC & 2 & 14.7-23.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano no-fucosilado + alto en manosa & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 6.2-11.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano no-fucosilado & HILIC & 2 & 0.5-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano alto en manosa & HILIC & 2 & 3.9-6.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano sialilado & HILIC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & \%G0F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 65.8-71.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & \%G1F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 12.8-16.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & \%G2F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 0.9-1.5\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Glicación & Cromatografía de afinidad de boronato & 3 & 0.1-0.6\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Carga & Variantes acídas & CEX & 2 & 8.2-12.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Variantes básicas & CEX & 2 & 20.6-31.5\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Pico principal & CEX-UPLC & 2 & 17.5-30.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & icIEF & 2 & 18.5-30.1\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Variantes isoeléctricas & cIEF & 3 & Patrón de carga similar y variantes de punto isoeléctrico & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & 2D-DIGE & 3 & Imagen similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
Hidrofobicidad & Hidrofobicidad & HIC & 3 & Perfil similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
Modificaciones de aminoácidos /
Variantes de secuencia & Oxidación de Met256 y Met34 & RP-HPLC-UV & 2 & 0.9-2.9\% & \makecell[c]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Deamidación en péptidos LH27 y LH30 & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.3-4.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Isomerización de Asp & ISOQUANT & 3 & 0.8-2.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 0.5-2.8\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Extensión N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & Sin detección de escisión incompleta del péptido & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Piroglutamato N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.2-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Lisina C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 13.3-18.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Prolina amida C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & 0.1-1.4\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Estructura de orden superior & Estructura secundaria & CD  UV-lejano & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & FTIR & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estructura terciaria & CD UV-cercano & 3 & Estructura terciaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Cristalografía de rayos X & 3 & Estructura cristalina similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Intercambio H / D & 3 & Estructura 3D similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Coeficiente de extinción & AAA / Pico Tag  & 3 & 1.47-1.49 & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   &  ACCQ Tag & 3 & 1.38 & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Temperatura de fusión & DSC & 3 & Tm1: 71.06, Tm2: 81.56 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estructura 3D & 1D 1H NMR & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & 2D 1H-1H NMR  & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \hline
Atributos relacionados Con el medicamento & Osmolalidad (mOsm/kg) & Osmómetro (depresión del punto de congelación de la solución) & 3 & 0.80-0.81 & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & pH & Potenciómetro & 3 & 5.2-5.3 & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Claridad & Inspección visual & 3 & Sin color a levemente amarilla & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Polisorbato 80 & Espectrofotometría de absorción infrarroja & 3 & 0.09\% & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Volumen extraíble & Peso & 2 & 771-831 $\upmu$L & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Contaminación por partículas & Inspección visual & 3 & Libre de partículas extrañas & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & MFI & 3 & $\geq$ 10 $\upmu$m: 104-208, $\geq$ 25 $\upmu$m: 1-2 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & RMM & 3 & No flotantes> 0.3 $\upmu$m: 5000-9000, 
Flotantes> 0.5 $\upmu$m: 2000-4000  & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Concentración de ingrediente activo  & UVS (280 nm) & 2 &  44.9-52.4 mg/mL & Sandoz \\ \hline
Actividad Biológica & Unión a TNF & Inhibición de la apoptosis celular inducida por sTNF-$\upalpha$ & 1 & 84-118\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión al TNF$\upalpha$ por SPR / por FRET & 1 & 80-120\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Estimulación de la apoptosis de células Jurkat inducida por mTNF-$\upalpha$ & 2 & 87-117\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Neutralización de TNF-$\upalpha$ (ensayo de gen reportero NF-k$\upbeta$) & 2 & 78-115\% & \makecell[c]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión mTNF por citometría de flujo & 2 & 80-113\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Inhibición de la expresión de la molécula de adhesión sVCAM-1 & 3 & 95-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a las citocinas: TGF-$\upbeta$1, IL-1$\upbeta$, IFN-$\upgamma$, 
APRIL, IL-6, IL- 8, IL-10, TNF-beta, sCD40L, BAFF y RANKL & 3 & No se presenta & \makecell[c]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Inducción de células reguladoras
(señalización inversa) & Ensayo MLR: incorporación de EdU por citometría de flujo & 3 & 0-70\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Expresión de macrófagos reguladores (CD206) por citometría de flujo & 3 & 69-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & ADCC & Ensayo de ADCC de células NK & 2 & 54-182\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & MLR & 3 & Inhibe la proliferación de células T
De una manera proporcional a la dosis & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa V158 por SPR & 2 & 69-115\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa F158 por SPR & 2 & 79-99\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & CDC & Ensayo CDC & 2 & 65-119\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a C1q por ELISA & 2 & 70-111\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Ensayos SPR adicionales de unión Al receptor Fc$\upgamma$ & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RI M 10-9 & 3 & 20.3-24.5 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIa $\upmu$M & 3 & 2.27-2.34 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIb/c $\upmu$M & 3 & 9.48-10.0 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIb & 3 & 9.67-11.8 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Vida media & Unión al receptor de FcRn por SPR & 2 & 67-150\% & Sandoz \\ \hline 
  Degradación  & 50 °C (2 semanas) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & 40 °C (3 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & 25 °C (6 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Exposición lumínica & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Deamidación forzada & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Oxidación forzada & Endopeptidasa de lisilo limitada & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \hline
Impurezas relacionadas al proceso & Proteina A & ELISA & 3 & < 1 ng/mg & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Proteinas celulares & HCP ELISA & 3 & 129-168 ppm & Amgen \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & 2D DIGE & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & DNA residual & qPCR & 3 & < 1pg/mg & Amgen \\ \hline
Inmunogenicidad & Ensayo ADA & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Ensayo Nab & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \hline
Estudios Preclínicos & Estudio toxicológico /toxicocinético & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estudio farmacocinético comparativo & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estudio farmacológico & Monos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Sandoz \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}  

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|c|L|c|}
\caption{Resumen de pruebas de presentadas por Amgen, Samsung, Sandoz y Pfizer para sustentar la demostración de biocomparabilidad de sus productos contra Humira (Amgen, 2016; Pfizer, 2019; Samsung, 2018; Sandoz, 2018), primera columna: Parámetro, segunda columna: atributo de calidad a medir, tercera columna, método utilizado para la medición, cuarta columna: nivel de análisis: nivel 1: Análisis de equivalencia estadística $\pm$ 1.5$\upsigma$ (Amgen, 2016), nivel 2: respeta el rango de calidad establecido para Humira $\pm$ 3$\upsigma$  (Sandoz, 2018) nivel 3: Visualmente similar a Humira (comparación de resultados lado a lado), quinta columna: datos pertenecientes a Humira, quinta columna: referencia. }
\label{}\\
\hline
\thead{Parámetro} 
  & \thead{Atributo de\\ Calidad} 
    & \thead{Método de\\ testeo} 
      & \thead{Nivel de\\ análisis} 
        & \thead{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)} 
          & \thead{Referencia} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Table \thetable:{} -- continued from previous page}\\
\hline
\thead{Parámetro} 
  & \thead{Atributo de\\ Calidad} 
    & \thead{Método de\\ testeo} 
      & \thead{Nivel de\\ análisis} 
        & \thead{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)} 
          & \thead{Referencia} \\ \hline
\endhead
Estructura primaria & Secuencia de aminoácidos & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & Cromatograma puede superponerse visualmente a Humira & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
 &  & LC/MS/MS (mapeos de péptidos ortogonales) & 3 & Secuencia de aminoácidos idéntica para ambas cadenas & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Puentes disulfuro & LC/MS (mapeo de péptidos en condiciones no reductoras) & 3 & Porcentaje relativo similar de enlaces
Disulfuro correctamente unidos & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Tioles libres & Ensayo de Ellman & 3 & Baja cantidad de tioles libres ($\leq$ 0.4 mol / mol) & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Enlaces tioéter & rCE-SDS & 3 & Baja cantidad de enlaces tioéter
Del pico de la cadena ligera-pesada & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
 & Masa molecular & UPLC-ESI-MS de proteína intacta (2H2L + 2G0F) / ESI-TOF-MS & 3 & 148.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
 &  & UPLC-ESI- MS - (R) de cadena pesada y cadena ligera & 3 & HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
 &  & UPLC-ESI-MS - (R / NR) de mAb desglicosilado (2H2L), LC, HC & 3 & 2H2L: 145.2 kDa. HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa,  & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & SE-HPLC / MALLS de monómero & 3 & 143.8-154.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Punto Isoeléctrico & cIEF & 3 & 8.45-8.46 & Amgen \\ \hline
Pureza & \% Principal & SE-HPLC & 2 & 99.2-99.6\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Monómeros & SEC & 2 & 99.5-99.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Variantes de peso molecular alto & SEC & 2 & 0.1-0.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & AUC & 2 & 0-2.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Dímeros & AUC & 3 & 0.5-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Fragmentos de mAb & SEC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & nrCE-SDS & 2 & LC: 0.1-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 5- 6}
  &   &   &   & HHL: 1.4-3.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & IgG intacta & nrCE-SDS & 2 & 95.6-97.9\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Glicosilación & Ocupación del sitio Fc N-glicano & rCE-SDS & 3 & 97.7-98.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Identificación de glicanos & UPLC-ESI-MS/MS con procainamida & 3 & 14 glicanos detectados & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano galactosilado & HILIC & 2 & 14.7-23.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano no-fucosilado + alto en manosa & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 6.2-11.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano no-fucosilado & HILIC & 2 & 0.5-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano alto en manosa & HILIC & 2 & 3.9-6.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & N-glicano sialilado & HILIC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & \%G0F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 65.8-71.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & \%G1F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 12.8-16.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & \%G2F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 0.9-1.5\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Glicación & Cromatografía de afinidad de boronato & 3 & 0.1-0.6\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Carga & Variantes acídas & CEX & 2 & 8.2-12.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Variantes básicas & CEX & 2 & 20.6-31.5\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Pico principal & CEX-UPLC & 2 & 17.5-30.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & icIEF & 2 & 18.5-30.1\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Variantes isoeléctricas & cIEF & 3 & Patrón de carga similar y variantes de punto isoeléctrico & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & 2D-DIGE & 3 & Imagen similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
Hidrofobicidad & Hidrofobicidad & HIC & 3 & Perfil similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
Modificaciones de aminoácidos /
Variantes de secuencia & Oxidación de Met256 y Met34 & RP-HPLC-UV & 2 & 0.9-2.9\% & \makecell[c]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Deamidación en péptidos LH27 y LH30 & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.3-4.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Isomerización de Asp & ISOQUANT & 3 & 0.8-2.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 0.5-2.8\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Extensión N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & Sin detección de escisión incompleta del péptido & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Piroglutamato N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.2-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Lisina C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 13.3-18.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Prolina amida C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & 0.1-1.4\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Estructura de orden superior & Estructura secundaria & CD  UV-lejano & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & FTIR & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estructura terciaria & CD UV-cercano & 3 & Estructura terciaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Cristalografía de rayos X & 3 & Estructura cristalina similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Intercambio H / D & 3 & Estructura 3D similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Coeficiente de extinción & AAA / Pico Tag  & 3 & 1.47-1.49 & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   &  ACCQ Tag & 3 & 1.38 & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Temperatura de fusión & DSC & 3 & Tm1: 71.06, Tm2: 81.56 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estructura 3D & 1D 1H NMR & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & 2D 1H-1H NMR  & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \hline
Atributos relacionados Con el medicamento & Osmolalidad (mOsm/kg) & Osmómetro (depresión del punto de congelación de la solución) & 3 & 0.80-0.81 & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & pH & Potenciómetro & 3 & 5.2-5.3 & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Claridad & Inspección visual & 3 & Sin color a levemente amarilla & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Polisorbato 80 & Espectrofotometría de absorción infrarroja & 3 & 0.09\% & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Volumen extraíble & Peso & 2 & 771-831 $\upmu$L & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Contaminación por partículas & Inspección visual & 3 & Libre de partículas extrañas & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & MFI & 3 & $\geq$ 10 $\upmu$m: 104-208, $\geq$ 25 $\upmu$m: 1-2 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & RMM & 3 & No flotantes> 0.3 $\upmu$m: 5000-9000, 
Flotantes> 0.5 $\upmu$m: 2000-4000  & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Concentración de ingrediente activo  & UVS (280 nm) & 2 &  44.9-52.4 mg/mL & Sandoz \\ \hline
Actividad Biológica & Unión a TNF & Inhibición de la apoptosis celular inducida por sTNF-$\upalpha$ & 1 & 84-118\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión al TNF$\upalpha$ por SPR / por FRET & 1 & 80-120\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Estimulación de la apoptosis de células Jurkat inducida por mTNF-$\upalpha$ & 2 & 87-117\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Neutralización de TNF-$\upalpha$ (ensayo de gen reportero NF-k$\upbeta$) & 2 & 78-115\% & \makecell[c]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión mTNF por citometría de flujo & 2 & 80-113\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Inhibición de la expresión de la molécula de adhesión sVCAM-1 & 3 & 95-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a las citocinas: TGF-$\upbeta$1, IL-1$\upbeta$, IFN-$\upgamma$, 
APRIL, IL-6, IL- 8, IL-10, TNF-beta, sCD40L, BAFF y RANKL & 3 & No se presenta & \makecell[c]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Inducción de células reguladoras
(señalización inversa) & Ensayo MLR: incorporación de EdU por citometría de flujo & 3 & 0-70\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Expresión de macrófagos reguladores (CD206) por citometría de flujo & 3 & 69-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & ADCC & Ensayo de ADCC de células NK & 2 & 54-182\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & MLR & 3 & Inhibe la proliferación de células T
De una manera proporcional a la dosis & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa V158 por SPR & 2 & 69-115\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa F158 por SPR & 2 & 79-99\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & CDC & Ensayo CDC & 2 & 65-119\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a C1q por ELISA & 2 & 70-111\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Ensayos SPR adicionales de unión Al receptor Fc$\upgamma$ & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RI M 10-9 & 3 & 20.3-24.5 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIa $\upmu$M & 3 & 2.27-2.34 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIb/c $\upmu$M & 3 & 9.48-10.0 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIb & 3 & 9.67-11.8 & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Vida media & Unión al receptor de FcRn por SPR & 2 & 67-150\% & Sandoz \\ \hline 
  Degradación  & 50 °C (2 semanas) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & 40 °C (3 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & 25 °C (6 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Exposición lumínica & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Deamidación forzada & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Oxidación forzada & Endopeptidasa de lisilo limitada & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \hline
Impurezas relacionadas al proceso & Proteina A & ELISA & 3 & < 1 ng/mg & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Proteinas celulares & HCP ELISA & 3 & 129-168 ppm & Amgen \\ \cline{ 3- 6}
  &   & 2D DIGE & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & DNA residual & qPCR & 3 & < 1pg/mg & Amgen \\ \hline
Inmunogenicidad & Ensayo ADA & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Ensayo Nab & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \hline
Estudios Preclínicos & Estudio toxicológico /toxicocinético & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estudio farmacocinético comparativo & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{ 2- 6}
  & Estudio farmacológico & Monos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Sandoz \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}  
\end{landscape}



\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{LLcLc}
\caption{Resumen de pruebas de presentadas por Amgen, Samsung, Sandoz y Pfizer para sustentar la demostración de biocomparabilidad de sus productos contra Humira (Amgen, 2016; Pfizer, 2019; Samsung, 2018; Sandoz, 2018), primera columna: Parámetro, segunda columna: atributo de calidad a medir, tercera columna, método utilizado para la medición, cuarta columna: nivel de análisis: nivel 1: Análisis de equivalencia estadística $\pm$ 1.5$\upsigma$ (Amgen, 2016), nivel 2: respeta el rango de calidad establecido para Humira $\pm$ 3$\upsigma$  (Sandoz, 2018) nivel 3: Visualmente similar a Humira (comparación de resultados lado a lado), quinta columna: datos pertenecientes a Humira, quinta columna: referencia. }
\label{}\\
\toprule
%\thead{Parámetro} 
   \thead[l]{Atributo de\\ Calidad} 
    & \thead[l]{Método de\\ testeo} 
      & \thead{Nivel de\\ análisis} 
        & \thead[l]{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)} 
          & \thead{Referencia} \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Table \thetable:{} -- continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
%\thead{Parámetro} 
   \thead[l]{Atributo de\\ Calidad} 
    & \thead[l]{Método de\\ testeo} 
      & \thead{Nivel de\\ análisis} 
        & \thead[l]{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)} 
          & \thead{Referencia} \\ \midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textit{Estructura primaria}}\\ 
\addlinespace
 Secuencia de aminoácidos & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & Cromatograma puede superponerse visualmente a Humira & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
   & LC/MS/MS (mapeos de péptidos ortogonales) & 3 & Secuencia de aminoácidos idéntica para ambas cadenas & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
  Puentes disulfuro & LC/MS (mapeo de péptidos en condiciones no reductoras) & 3 & Porcentaje relativo similar  de enlaces
Disulfuro correctamente unidos & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
  Tioles libres & Ensayo de Ellman & 3 & Baja cantidad de tioles libres ($\leq$ 0.4 mol / mol) & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
  Enlaces tioéter & rCE-SDS & 3 & Baja cantidad de enlaces tioéter
Del pico de la cadena ligera-pesada & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
  Masa molecular & UPLC-ESI-MS de proteína intacta (2H2L + 2G0F) / ESI-TOF-MS & 3 & 148.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \addlinespace
   & UPLC-ESI- MS - (R) de cadena pesada y cadena ligera & 3 & HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa & Samsung \\ \addlinespace
   & UPLC-ESI-MS - (R / NR) de mAb desglicosilado (2H2L), LC, HC & 3 & 2H2L: 145.2 kDa. HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa,  & Samsung \\ \addlinespace
     & SE-HPLC / MALLS de monómero & 3 & 143.8-154.1 kDa & Samsung \\\addlinespace 
   Punto Isoeléctrico & cIEF & 3 & 8.45-8.46 & Amgen \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textit{Pureza}}\\ \addlinespace
 \% Principal & SE-HPLC & 2 & 99.2-99.6\% & Samsung \\ \addlinespace
   Monómeros & SEC & 2 & 99.5-99.9\% & Sandoz \\\addlinespace
   Variantes de peso molecular alto & SEC & 2 & 0.1-0.4\% & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
     & AUC & 2 & 0-2.2\% & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
   Dímeros & AUC & 3 & 0.5-2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
   Fragmentos de mAb & SEC & 2 & 0-0.2\% & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
     & nrCE-SDS & 2 & LC: 0.1-0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
     &   &   & HHL: 1.4-3.1\% & Sandoz \\ \addlinespace
   IgG intacta & nrCE-SDS & 2 & 95.6-97.9\% & Sandoz \\ \midrule
\end{xltabular}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table is very huge (4 page lenght) ... and filled with lot of clutter, i.e. all `\multicolumn` commands are superfluous, etc. Since your document preamble is unknown, the MWE below consider that page margin are 20mm wide, for fonts are used default font, the Greek letters are standard. Also are corrected some value with units (for all I haven't time, so I left them to you).

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow,xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                              |>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                              |L
                              |c
                              |L
                              |c|}
\caption{Resumen de pruebas de presentadas por Amgen, Samsung, Sandoz y Pfizer para sustentar la demostración de biocomparabilidad de sus productos contra Humira (Amgen, 2016; Pfizer, 2019; Samsung, 2018; Sandoz, 2018), primera columna: Parámetro, segunda columna: atributo de calidad a medir, tercera columna, método utilizado para la medición, cuarta columna: nivel de análisis: nivel 1: Análisis de equivalencia estadística \SI{\pm 5}{\sigma} (Amgen, 2016), nivel 2: respeta el rango de calidad establecido para Humira \SI{\pm 3}{\sigma}  (Sandoz, 2018) nivel 3: Visualmente similar a Humira (comparación de resultados lado a lado), quinta columna: datos pertenecientes a Humira, quinta columna: referencia. }
\label{tab:huge}\\
%
    \hline
Parámetro
    & \makecell{Atributo de\\ Calidad}
        & \makecell{Método de\\testeo }
            & \makecell{Nivel de\\ análisis}
                & \makecell{Rango de\\ Humira (EU)}
                    & Referencia \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Contionue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
% TABLE BODY
\multirow[t]{28}{=}{Estructura primaria}
    & Secuencia de aminoácidos
        & RP-HPLC-UV
            & 3 & Cromatograma puede superponerse visualmente a Humira
                    & Sandoz \\*
   \cline{3-6}
    &   & LC/MS/MS (mapeos de péptidos ortogonales)
            & 3 & Secuencia de aminoácidos idéntica para ambas cadenas
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Puentes disulfuro
        & LC/MS (mapeo de péptidos en condiciones no reductoras)
            & 3 & Porcentaje relativo similar de enlaces Disulfuro correctamente unidos
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Tioles libres
        & Ensayo de Ellman
            & 3 & Baja cantidad de tioles libres (\SI{\leq 0.4}{mol/mol})
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Enlaces tioéter
        & rCE-SDS
            & 3 & Baja cantidad de enlaces tioéter Del pico de la cadena ligera-pesada
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Masa molecular
        & UPLC-ESI-MS de proteína intacta (2H2L + 2G0F) / ESI-TOF-MS
            & 3 & 148.1 kDa
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & UPLC-ESI- MS - (R) de cadena pesada y cadena ligera
            & 3 & HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & UPLC-ESI-MS - (R / NR) de mAb desglicosilado (2H2L), LC, HC
            & 3 & 2H2L: 145.2 kDa. HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa,
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & SE-HPLC / MALLS de monómero
            & 3 & 143.8-154.1 kDa
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Punto Isoeléctrico
        & cIEF
            & 3 & 8.45-8.46
                    & Amgen \\
    \hline
\multirow[t]{9}{=}{Pureza}
    & \% Principal & SE-HPLC
        & 2 & 99.2-99.6\%
                & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Monómeros
        & SEC
            & 2 & 99.5-99.9\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Variantes de peso molecular alto}
        & SEC
            & 2 & 0.1-0.4\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & AUC
            & 2 & 0-2.2\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Dímeros
        & AUC
            & 3 & 0.5-2.3\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Fragmentos de mAb
        & SEC
            & 2 & 0-0.2\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & nrCE-SDS
            & 2 & LC: 0.1-0.9\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{ 5- 6}
    &   &   &   & HHL: 1.4-3.1\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & IgG intacta
        & nrCE-SDS
            & 2 & 95.6-97.9\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
\multirow[t]{13}{=}{Glicosilación}
    & Ocupación del sitio Fc N-glicano
        & rCE-SDS
            & 3 & 97.7-98.6\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Identificación de glicanos
        & UPLC-ESI-MS/MS con procainamida
            & 3 & 14 glicanos detectados
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & N-glicano galactosilado
        & HILIC
            & 2 & 14.7-23.1\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & N-glicano no-fucosilado + alto en manosa
        & HILIC-UPLC
            & 2 & 6.2-11.4\%
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & N-glicano no-fucosilado
        & HILIC
            & 2 & 0.5-0.9\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & N-glicano alto en manosa
        & HILIC
            & 2 & 3.9-6.6\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & N-glicano sialilado
        & HILIC
            & 2 & 0-0.2\%
                    & Pfizer \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & \%G0F
        & HILIC-UPLC
            & 2 & 65.8-71.2\%
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & \%G1F
        & HILIC-UPLC
            & 2 & 12.8-16.4\%
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & \%G2F
        & HILIC-UPLC
            & 2 & 0.9-1.5\%
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Glicación
        & Cromatografía de afinidad de boronato
            & 3 & 0.1-0.6\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
%%% new page (2)
\pagebreak
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{Carga}
    & Variantes acídas
        & CEX
            & 2 & 8.2-12.6\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Variantes básicas
        & CEX
            & 2 & 20.6-31.5\%
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Pico principal
        & CEX-UPLC
            & 2 & 17.5-30.2\%
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & icIEF
            & 2 & 18.5-30.1\%
                    & Samsung \\*
    \cline{2-6}
    & Variantes isoeléctricas
        & cIEF
            & 3 & Patrón de carga similar y variantes de punto isoeléctrico
                    & Sandoz \\*
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & 2D-DIGE
            & 3 & Imagen similar
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
Hidrofobicidad
    & Hidrofobicidad
        & HIC
            & 3 & Perfil similar
                & Sandoz \\
    \hline
\multirow[t]{13}{=}{Modificaciones de aminoácidos /
                   Variantes de secuencia}
    & Oxidación de Met256 y Met34
        & RP-HPLC-UV
            & 2 & 0.9-2.9\%
                    & \makecell[l]{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Deamidación en péptidos LH27 y LH30
        & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS
            & 3 & 1.3-4.4\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Isomerización de Asp
        & ISOQUANT
            & 3 & 0.8-2.7\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & RP-HPLC-UV
            & 3 & 0.5-2.8\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Extensión N-terminal
        & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS
            & 3 & Sin detección de escisión incompleta del péptido
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Piroglutamato N-terminal
        & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS
            & 3 & 1.2-2.3\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Lisina C-terminal
        & RP-HPLC-UV
            & 3 & 13.3-18.7\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Prolina amida C-terminal
        & RP-HPLC-UV
            & 3 & 0.1-1.4\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
\multirow[t]{17}{=}{Estructura de orden superior}
    & Estructura secundaria
        & CD  UV-lejano
            & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & FTIR
            & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Estructura terciaria
        & CD UV-cercano
            & 3 & Estructura terciaria similar
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &    & Cristalografía de rayos X
            & 3 & Estructura cristalina similar
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &    & Intercambio H / D
            & 3 & Estructura 3D similar
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Coeficiente de extinción
        & AAA / Pico Tag
            & 3 & 1.47-1.49
                    & Samsung \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &    &  ACCQ Tag
            & 3 & 1.38
                    & Samsung \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Temperatura de fusión
        & DSC
            & 3 & Tm1: 71.06, Tm2: 81.56
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Estructura 3D
        & 1D 1H NMR
            & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &    & 2D 1H-1H NMR
            & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{Atributos relacionados Con el medicamento}
    & Osmolalidad (mOsm/kg)
        & Osmómetro (depresión del punto de congelación de la solución)
            & 3 & 0.80-0.81
                    & Amgen \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & pH
        & Potenciómetro
            & 3 & 5.2-5.3
                    & Amgen \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Claridad
        & Inspección visual
            & 3 & Sin color a levemente amarilla
                    & Amgen \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Polisorbato 80
        & Espectrofotometría de absorción infrarroja
            & 3 & 0.09\%
                    & Amgen \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Volumen extraíble
        & Peso
            & 2 & \SIrange{771}{831}{\micro L }
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Contaminación por partículas
        & Inspección visual
            & 3 & Libre de partículas extrañas
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & MFI
            & 3 & \SI{\geq 10}{\micro\metre}: 104-208,
                  \SI{\geq 25}{\micro\metre}: 1-2
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & RMM
            & 3 & No flotantes \SI{> 0.3}{\micro\metre}: 5000-9000,
                  Flotantes \SI{> 0.5}{\micro\metre}: 2000-4000
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Concentración de ingrediente activo
        & UVS (\SI{280}{nm})
            & 2 & \SIrange{44.9}{52.4}{mg/mL}
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
%%% new page (2)
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{Actividad Biológica}
    & Unión a TNF
        & Inhibición de la apoptosis celular inducida por sTNF-$alpha$
            & 1 & 84-118\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión al TNF$\alpha$ por SPR / por FRET
            & 1 & 80-120\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Estimulación de la apoptosis de células Jurkat inducida por mTNF-$\alpha$
            & 2 & 87-117\% & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & Neutralización de TNF-$\alpha$ (ensayo de gen reportero NF-k$\beta$)
            & 2 & 78-115\%
                    & \makecell{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión mTNF por citometría de flujo
            & 2 & 80-113\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Inhibición de la expresión de la molécula de adhesión sVCAM-1
            & 3 & 95-120\%
                    & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a las citocinas: TGF-$\beta$1,
          IL-1$\beta$, IFN-$\gamma$,
          APRIL, IL-6, IL- 8, IL-10, TNF-beta, sCD40L, BAFF y RANKL
            & 3 & No se presenta
                    & \makecell{Sandoz,\\ Samsung} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Inducción de células reguladoras (señalización inversa)
        & Ensayo MLR: incorporación de EdU por citometría de flujo
            & 3 & 0-70\%
                    & Samsung \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Expresión de macrófagos reguladores (CD206) por citometría de flujo
            & 3 & 69-120\%
                    & Samsung \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & ADCC
        & Ensayo de ADCC de células NK
            & 2 & 54-182\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & MLR
            & 3 & Inhibe la proliferación de células T De una manera proporcional a la dosis
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a Fc$gamma$RIIIa V158 por SPR
            & 2 & 69-115\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a Fc$\gamma$RIIIa F158 por SPR
            & 2 & 79-99\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & CDC
        & Ensayo CDC
            & 2 & 65-119\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a C1q por ELISA
            & 2 & 70-111\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Ensayos SPR adicionales de unión Al receptor Fc$\gamma$
        & Unión a Fc$\gamma$RI M 10-9
            & 3 & 20.3-24.5
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a Fc$\gamma$RIIa $\mu$M
            & 3 & 2.27-2.34
                & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a Fc$\gamma$RIIb/c $\mu$M
            & 3 & 9.48-10.0
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & Unión a Fc$gamma$RIIIb
            & 3 & 9.67-11.8
                    & Sandoz \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Vida media
        & Unión al receptor de FcRn por SPR
            & 2 & 67-150\%
                    & Sandoz \\
    \hline
%%%% new page (3)
\pagebreak
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{Degradación} 
    & \SI{50}{\celsius} (2 semanas) 
        & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & \SI{40}{\celsius} (3 meses) 
        & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & 25 °C (6 meses) 
        & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Exposición lumínica 
        & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Pfizer \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Deamidación forzada 
        & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Pfizer \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Oxidación forzada 
        & Endopeptidasa de lisilo limitada 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Pfizer \\ 
    \hline
\multirow[t]{5}{=}{Impurezas relacionadas al proceso} 
    & Proteina A 
        & ELISA 
            & 3 & \SI{< 1}{ng/mg} 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Proteinas celulares
        & HCP ELISA 
            & 3 & \SIrange{129}{168}{ppm} 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{3-6}
    &   & 2D DIGE 
            & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & DNA residual 
        & qPCR
            & 3 & \SI{< 1}{pg/mg}
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \hline
\multirow[t]{2}{=}{Inmunogenicidad} 
    & Ensayo ADA 
        & MSD platform: biotin 
            & - & Comparable a US-Humira 
                    & Samsung \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Ensayo Nab 
        & MSD platform: biotin 
            & - & Comparable a US-Humira 
                    & Samsung \\ 
    \hline
\multirow[t]{2}{=}{Estudios Preclínicos} 
    & Estudio toxicológico/toxicocinético
        & Monos cinomolgos 
            & - & Comparable a US-Humira 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Estudio farmacocinético comparativo 
        & Monos cinomolgos 
            & - & Comparable a US-Humira 
                    & Amgen \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
    & Estudio farmacológico 
        & Monos 
            & - & Comparable a US-Humira 
                    & Sandoz \\ 
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses a `longtable` environment. The table's length exceeds 6 pages!

I would definitely move the caption to the top of the table. And, do consider using the `\si` and `\SI` macros of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units and their associated numbers.

The following screenshot shows just the caption, the legend (split off from the caption), and the first few rows of the body of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % choose a suitable document class
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set suitable page size parameters
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\newlength\mylenA \settowidth\mylenA{Nivel de}
\newlength\mylenB \settowidth\mylenB{Samsung}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|
           P{0.2\textwidth}|
      *{2}{C{0.15\textwidth}|}
           C{\mylenA}|
           C{0.15\textwidth}|
           C{\mylenB}|}

%% Headers and footers:

\caption{Resumen de pruebas de presentadas por Amgen, Samsung, Sandoz y Pfizer para sustentar la demostración de biocomparabilidad de sus productos contra Humira (Amgen, 2016; Pfizer, 2019; Samsung, 2018; Sandoz, 2018)} 
\label{tab:very_long_table}\\

% I suggest you split off the legend from the caption.
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}{%
Primera columna: Parámetro. Segunda columna: atributo de calidad a medir. Tercera columna, método utilizado para la medición. Cuarta columna: nivel de análisis; nivel~1: Análisis de equivalencia estadística ${}\pm1.5\upsigma$ (Amgen, 2016); nivel~2: respeta el rango de calidad establecido para Humira ${}\pm3\upsigma$  (Sandoz, 2018); nivel~3: Visualmente similar a Humira (comparación de resultados lado a lado). Quinta columna: datos pertenecientes a Humira. Quinta columna: referencia.}\\

\hline
Parámetro & Atributo de Calidad & Método de testeo & Nivel de análisis & Rango de Humira (EU) & Referencia \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\small \tablename~\thetable, continúa de la página anterior}\\[0.5ex]
\hline
Parámetro & Atributo de Calidad & Método de testeo & Nivel de análisis & Rango de Humira (EU) & Referencia \\ 
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continúa en la página siguiente)}\\
\endfoot

\endlastfoot % nothing special to do at very end

%% Body of table:

Estructura primaria & Secuencia de aminoácidos & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & Cromatograma puede superponerse visualmente a Humira & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & LC/MS/MS (mapeos de péptidos ortogonales) & 3 & Secuencia de aminoácidos idéntica para ambas cadenas & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Puentes disulfuro & LC/MS (mapeo de péptidos en condiciones no reductoras) & 3 & Porcentaje relativo similar de enlaces
Disulfuro correctamente unidos & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Tioles libres & Ensayo de Ellman & 3 & Baja cantidad de tioles libres ($\leq$ 0.4 mol / mol) & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Enlaces tioéter & rCE-SDS & 3 & Baja cantidad de enlaces tioéter
Del pico de la cadena ligera-pesada & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Masa molecular & UPLC-ESI-MS de proteína intacta (2H2L + 2G0F) / ESI-TOF-MS & 3 & 148.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & UPLC-ESI-MS-(R) de cadena pesada y cadena ligera & 3 & HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & UPLC-ESI-MS-(R/NR) de mAb desglicosilado (2H2L), LC, HC & 3 & 2H2L: 145.2 kDa. HC+G0F:50.6 kDa, LC:23.4 kDa,  & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & SE-HPLC / MALLS de monómero & 3 & 143.8--154.1 kDa & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Punto Isoeléctrico & cIEF & 3 & 8.45--8.46 & Amgen \\ \hline
Pureza & \% Principal & SE-HPLC & 2 & 99.2--99.6\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Monómeros & SEC & 2 & 99.5--99.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Variantes de peso molecular alto & SEC & 2 & 0.1-0.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & AUC & 2 & 0--2.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Dímeros & AUC & 3 & 0.5--2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Fragmentos de mAb & SEC & 2 & 0--0.2\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & nrCE-SDS & 2 & LC: 0.1--0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{ 5- 6}
 &  &  &  & HHL: 1.4--3.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & IgG intacta & nrCE-SDS & 2 & 95.6--97.9\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Glicosilación & Ocupación del sitio Fc N-glicano & rCE-SDS & 3 & 97.7--98.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Identificación de glicanos & UPLC-ESI-MS/MS con procainamida & 3 & 14 glicanos detectados & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & N-glicano galactosilado & HILIC & 2 & 14.7--23.1\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & N-glicano no-fucosilado + alto en manosa & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 6.2--11.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & N-glicano no-fucosilado & HILIC & 2 & 0.5--0.9\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & N-glicano alto en manosa & HILIC & 2 & 3.9--6.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & N-glicano sialilado & HILIC & 2 & 0--0.2\% & Pfizer \\ \cline{2-6}
 & \%G0F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 65.8--71.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & \%G1F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 12.8--16.4\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & \%G2F & HILIC-UPLC & 2 & 0.9--1.5\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Glicación & Cromatografía de afinidad de boronato & 3 & 0.1--0.6\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Carga & Variantes acídas & CEX & 2 & 8.2--12.6\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Variantes básicas & CEX & 2 & 20.6--31.5\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Pico principal & CEX-UPLC & 2 & 17.5--30.2\% & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & icIEF & 2 & 18.5-30.1\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Variantes isoeléctricas & cIEF & 3 & Patrón de carga similar y variantes de punto isoeléctrico & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & 2D-DIGE & 3 & Imagen similar & Sandoz \\ \hline
Hidrofobicidad & Hidrofobicidad & HIC & 3 & Perfil similar & Sandoz  \\  \hline
Modificaciones de aminoácidos\slash
Variantes de secuencia & Oxidación de Met256 y Met34 & RP-HPLC-UV & 2 & 0.9--2.9\% & Sandoz, Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Deamidación en péptidos LH27 y LH30 & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.3--4.4\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Isomerización de Asp & ISOQUANT & 3 & 0.8--2.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 0.5--2.8\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Extensión N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & Sin detección de escisión incompleta del péptido & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Piroglutamato N-terminal & Mapeo de péptidos por LC/MS & 3 & 1.2--2.3\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Lisina C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV  & 3 & 13.3--18.7\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Prolina amida C-terminal & RP-HPLC-UV & 3 & 0.1--1.4\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Estructura de orden superior & Estructura secundaria & CD  UV-lejano & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & FTIR & 3 & Estrutura secundaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Estructura terciaria & CD UV-cercano & 3 & Estructura terciaria similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Cristalografía de rayos X & 3 & Estructura cristalina similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Intercambio H / D & 3 & Estructura 3D similar & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Coeficiente de extinción & AAA / Pico Tag  & 3 & 1.47--1.49 & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  &  ACCQ Tag & 3 & 1.38 & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Temperatura de fusión & DSC & 3 & Tm1: 71.06, Tm2: 81.56 & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Estructura 3D & 1D 1H NMR & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & 2D 1H-1H NMR  & 3 & Espectros similares de NMR & Sandoz \\ \hline
Atributos relacionados
Con el medicamento & Osmolalidad (mOsm/kg) & Osmómetro (depresión del punto de congelación de la solución) & 3 & 0.80--0.81 & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & pH & Potenciómetro & 3 & 5.2-5.3 & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Claridad & Inspección visual & 3 & Sin color a levemente amarilla & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Polisorbato 80 & Espectrofotometría de absorción infrarroja & 3 & 0.09\% & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Volumen extraíble & Peso & 2 & 771--831\,\si{\micro\liter} & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Contaminación por partículas & Inspección visual & 3 & Libre de partículas extrañas & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & MFI & 3 & $\geq$ \SI{10}{\micro\meter}: 104--208, $\geq$ \SI{25}{\micro\meter}: 1--2 & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & RMM & 3 & No flotantes >0,3 \si{\micro\meter}: 5000--9000, 
Flotantes >0.5 \si{\micro\meter}: 2000--4000  & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Concentración de ingrediente activo  & UVS (280 nm) & 2 &  44.9--52.4 mg/mL & Sandoz \\ \hline
Actividad Biológica & Unión a TNF & Inhibición de la apoptosis celular inducida por sTNF-$\upalpha$ & 1 & 84--118\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión al TNF$\upalpha$ por SPR / por FRET & 1 & 80--120\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Estimulación de la apoptosis de células Jurkat inducida por mTNF-$\upalpha$ & 2 & 87--117\% & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Neutralización de TNF-$\upalpha$ (ensayo de gen reportero NF-k$\upbeta$) & 2 & 78--115\% & Sandoz, Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión mTNF por citometría de flujo & 2 & 80-113\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Inhibición de la expresión de la molécula de adhesión sVCAM-1 & 3 & 95--120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a las citocinas: TGF-$\upbeta$1, IL-1$\upbeta$, IFN-$\upgamma$, 
APRIL, IL-6, IL- 8, IL-10, TNF-beta, sCD40L, BAFF y RANKL & 3 & No se presenta & Sandoz, Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Inducción de células reguladoras
(señalización inversa) & Ensayo MLR: incorporación de EdU por citometría de flujo & 3 & 0-70\% & Samsung \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Expresión de macrófagos reguladores (CD206) por citometría de flujo & 3 & 69-120\% & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & ADCC & Ensayo de ADCC de células NK & 2 & 54-182\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & MLR & 3 & Inhibe la proliferación de células T
De una manera proporcional a la dosis & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa V158 por SPR & 2 & 69-115\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIa F158 por SPR & 2 & 79-99\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & CDC & Ensayo CDC & 2 & 65-119\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a C1q por ELISA & 2 & 70-111\% & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Ensayos SPR adicionales de unión
Al receptor Fc$\upgamma$ & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RI M 10-9 & 3 & 20.3-24.5 & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIa \si{\micro\mole} & 3 & 2.27-2.34 & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIb/c \si{\micro\mole} & 3 & 9.48-10.0 & Sandoz \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Unión a Fc$\upgamma$RIIIb & 3 & 9.67-11.8 & Sandoz \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Vida media & Unión al receptor de FcRn por SPR & 2 & 67-150\% & Sandoz \\ \hline
Degradación & 50 °C (2 semanas) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & 40 °C (3 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & 25 °C (6 meses) & SE-HPLC, rCE-SDS, CEX-HPLC (Bioensayo de potencia; Inhibición de apoptosis) & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Exposición lumínica & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Deamidación forzada & pH, concentración de proteína, variantes de carga, potencia & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Oxidación forzada & Endopeptidasa de lisilo limitada & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Pfizer \\ \hline
Impurezas relacionadas al proceso & Proteina A & ELISA & 3 & < 1 ng/mg & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Proteinas celulares & HCP ELISA & 3 & 129-168 ppm & Amgen \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & 2D DIGE & 3 & Visualmente similar a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & DNA residual & qPCR & 3 & < 1pg/mg & Amgen \\ \hline
Inmunogenicidad & Ensayo ADA & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Ensayo Nab & MSD platform: biotin & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Samsung \\ \hline
Estudios Preclínicos & Estudio toxicológico\slash toxicocinético & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Estudio farmacocinético comparativo & Monos cinomolgos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Amgen \\ \cline{2-6}
 & Estudio farmacológico & Monos & - & Comparable a US-Humira & Sandoz \\ \hline

\end{longtable}  
\end{document}
```